# convert python code into modular python

Tags: python, modular

im having trouble converting my python code into modular python. Can anyone help me out?

```
keep_going = "y"

while keep_going == "y":
    sales = float(input("Enter the amount of sales: "))
    comm_rate = .10

    commission = sales * comm_rate

    print ("The commission is: ", commission)

    keep_going = input("Do you want to calculate another commission? (Enter y for yes): ")

main()
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking

Comment: are you trying to make this a module?

Comment: What's `main()`? Is that the `while` loop you wrote?

Comment: Your code, as written, does not run due to bad indentation. Please fix that and show runnable code (or code where you point out the error). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is *"modular python"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def main():
    keep_going = "y"

    while keep_going.lower() in ['y', 'yes'],:
        sales = float(input("Enter the amount of sales: "))
        comm_rate = .10
        commission = sales * comm_rate
        print ("The commission is: ", commission)

        keep_going = input("Do you want to calculate another commission? (Enter y for yes): ")

main()
```